# Flag if there is a JOIN - SQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Two tables with same field names >> student.id in student table (a) and student.id in record table (b)

If student.id from student table is also in record table (join on a.student.id = b.student.id) then say "Yes" else "No" as "match"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no duplicates, then you can use a `left join`:

```
select s.*, (case when r.student_id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end)
from students s left join
     records r
     on r.student_id = s.id;
```

If there can be duplicates, then remove the duplicates before joining:

```
select s.*, (case when r.student_id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end)
from students s left join
     (select distinct r.student_id
      from records r
     ) r
     on r.student_id = s.id;
```

Comment: I would use the second one, to be on the safe side.

Comment: The second one works correctly, the table does have duplicates so second one flagged accurately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a LEFT JOIN which will show all the records from the first table, plus any matching records from the second table. You could use a CASE statement to display whether they match.

```
SELECT
    A.StudentID,
    B.StudentID,
    CASE WHEN b.StudentID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END As Match
FROM
    StudentA a
    LEFT JOIN StudentB b on a.StudentID = b.StudentID
```

Comment: This will work well in cases when there are single matches between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a left join and a case when

```
select  case when b.student_id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' END match
from  student a
left join  record  b on a.student_id = b.student_id
```

Comment: This will work well in cases when there are single matches between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The following is safe from duplicates and probably faster if there are many duplicates.

```
select *, 
case when exists (select null from other_students b 
                  where b.id = a.id) then 'Yes' else 'No' end student_match
from students a
```

See the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/61efd/1) in action here.

Comment: This returns an error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10249]: line 3:30 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'parent_id': Currently SubQuery expressions are only allowed as Where Clause predicates

Comment: You did not specify the DBMS. I ran this on PostgreSQL (see Fiddle link) which allows it.

Comment: Sorry, it's Hive/Hadoop. Trying some variations of this, thanks for responding.